# Create custom directive that will run a function on an event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-directive

In angularjs I had a directive:

```
export default angular.module('cd.enter', [])
    .directive('cdEnter', () => {
        return {
            link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
                element.bind("keydown", (event) => {
                    if (!event.shiftKey && event.which === 13) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });

                element.bind("keyup", (event) => {
                    if (!event.shiftKey && event.which === 13) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        scope.$apply(() => {
                            scope.$eval(attrs.cdEnter);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

This would allow a newline inside a textarea with `shift + enter` and would then run a function if just `enter` was pressed.

How can I reproduce this in angular? The following will bind to the `keyup` and `keydown` events, but I need to know how to get the function, and then run it in the correct context.

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cdEnter]'
})
export class EnterDirective {
  @Input() cdEnter: Function;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    if (!event.shiftKey && event.which === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyUp(event) {
    if (!event.shiftKey && event.which === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //How to perform the equivalent in Angular
      //scope.$apply(() => {
      //  scope.$eval(this.cdEnter);
      //});
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `event.shiftKey` and `event.which`. Angular provides a nice high level API for handling events in a declarative manner.  You can just type `keydown.shift.enter` in the `@HostBinding()` args.

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cdEnter]'
})
export class EnterDirective {
  @Input() cdEnter: Function;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('keydown.shift.enter', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.cdEnter();
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5avqx)

Comment: To add to the answer, to call a function and pass parameters you must bind with your current context: `[cdEnter]="callback.bind(this, 'Hello ', 'world!')` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuokme